# Read File using StreamResourceInfo GetResourceStream(Uri uriResource)

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

I want to read file using StreamResourceInfo `GetResourceStream(Uri uriResource)` method where my filename is Assets and its type if file (extension) so I used following line of code in windows phone 8.1 sdk,

```
StreamResourceInfo info = App.GetResourceStream(new Uri("Assets", UriKind.Relative));
```

But the info variable shows null value.

Answer (score 0):

Is it necessary to use `GetResourceStream` in your case? Your question is a little bit unclear, but if you want to get the content of the file you can try this:

```
public async Task<string> GetFileContent(string fileName)
    {
        try
        {
            string text = string.Empty;
            StorageFile storageFile = await Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFileAsync(fileName);
            if (storageFile != null)
            {
                IBuffer buffer = await FileIO.ReadBufferAsync(storageFile);
                DataReader reader = DataReader.FromBuffer(buffer);
                byte[] fileContent = new byte[reader.UnconsumedBufferLength];
                reader.ReadBytes(fileContent);
                text = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(fileContent, 0, fileContent.Length);
            }

            return text;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }
    }
```

Note, it returns string UTF8 encoded, you can change it if necessary.

usage:

```
var fileContent = await GetFileContent(@"Assets\[yourfile]");
```